# Unexpected result with siblings container not being correctly aligned

Tags: html, css

I have the current [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/dkyzavj6/)

in which I wish to include a scroll-x instead of wrapping:

```
+----------------------------------+
|+---------+ +--------------------+|
||  33%    | |  width: normally   ||
||         | |  66%; otherwise    ||
|| min:    | |  min-width:600px   ||
||   300px | |                    ||
|+---------+ +--------------------+|
+----------------------------------+
|<|                 |=|          |>|
+----------------------------------+
```

This works, only when I have different amounts of text entered, the dives are not aligned to top:

Instead:

```
+----------------------------------+
|+---------+                       |
||         |                       |
||         | +--------------------+|
||         | |                    ||
||         | |                    ||   <----  I get something like this
|+---------+ +--------------------+|
+----------------------------------+
|<|                 |=|          |>|          
+----------------------------------+
```

Is there a fool-proof way of ensuring that (instead) they go like:

```
+----------------------------------+
|+---------+ +--------------------+|
||         | |                    ||
||         | |                    ||
||         | +--------------------+|
||         |                       |   
|+---------+                       |
+----------------------------------+
|<|                 |=|          |>|          
+----------------------------------+
```

My css looks like:

```
.firstDiv{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:300px; 
    width:33%;
    background-color:red; 
    white-space:normal;
}
.secondDiv{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:600px; 
    width:66%;
    background-color:orange; 
    white-space:normal;
}

.parent{
    overflow-x:scroll; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    background-color:blue;
    height:400px; 
    width:100%; 
    top:0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that I would have content below it too, something like:

```
+----------------------------------+
|+---------+ +--------------------+|
||         | |                    ||
||         | |                    ||
||         | +--------------------+|
||         |                       |   
|+---------+                       |
|+---------+ +--------------------+|
||         | |                    ||
|+---------+ +--------------------+|
+----------------------------------+
|<|                 |=|          |>|          
+----------------------------------+
```

etc.

Comment: You need to align those boxes in top? you can use `vertical-align: top;` at `firstDiv` then

Comment: I was doing that, only my problem was then in a more complex (although inevitable) situation where I would have content below I'd want them aligned too (in same container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `vertical-align: top;` for those divs:

```
.firstDiv{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:300px; 
    width:33%;
    background-color:red; 
    white-space:normal;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.secondDiv{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:600px; 
    width:66%;
    background-color:orange; 
    white-space:normal;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dkyzavj6/2/)

[check this demo with your updated question](http://jsfiddle.net/dkyzavj6/3/) : after the second div I've used `clear: both;` to go them below.

Comment: Cheers. I'd heard of clear before but never bothered learning what it does! thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add `vertical-align: top` at `firstDiv` element

```
.firstDiv{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:300px; 
    width:33%;
    background-color:red; 
    white-space:normal;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/dkyzavj6/1/